# get xml node value using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem where I need to get the value of a specific node in c#

I have this sample `XML-Code` and here is my C# code

```
    string xml = @"
            <ChapterHeader>
        <Text> I need to get the text here</Text>
    </ChapterHeader>
            ";
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
                    if (rdr.LocalName == "ChapterHeader")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The desired output is

```
<Text> I need to get the text here</Text>
```

including the Text Node. How can i do that? thank you

I also need to loop a huge xml file

and I need to get the value of a specific node

and I need to skip some specific node also.
example I have a  node. the program must not read that Node and its childen Node.

How can i do that?

```
<ChapterHeader>
    <Text> I need to get the text here</Text>
</ChapterHeader>
<Blank>
    <Not>
    </Not>
</Blank>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The desired output is
>
> ```
> <Text> I need to get the text here</Text>
> ```

Look for [`ReadInnerXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readinnerxml(v=vs.110).aspx) which reads all the content, including markup, as a string.

```
Console.WriteLine( rdr.ReadInnerXml());
```

In the following question, you want to deal with larger `Xml`. I prefer `Linq` to `Xml` when dealing with larger set.

> The program must not read that Node and its childen Node

Yes, it is possible. You could do something like this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("filepath");

var nestedElementValues = 
doc.Descendants("ChapterHeader")    // flattens hierarchy and look for specific name.
   .Elements()                      // Get elements for found element
   .Select(x=>(string)x.Value);     // Read the value.
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X6mUPA)

Comment: thank you that worked. i have another question. kindly help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Xml.Linq` is a newer library designed to get rid of undesired reader style.

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var texts = document.Descendants("Text");

foreach (var text in texts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Hello Tommy. that's great. its working. but i have another question: i need to loop a huge xml file. and get the value of its sub Node. and some of the node. i dont need to read its children node if the parent node is <blank>. how can i do that?  please tell me if my second question is not clear. thank yuo

Comment: I am sorry that you cannot skip node in reading XML. It is because without reading sequentially, reader don't know where XML tags end. Unless you write your own reader with special rules which is probably not worth it. How big is your file?

Comment: less than 1 mb. so can you recommend some way sir? to do it? thank you

Comment: 1MB is just tiny. Even 10MB, it will be parsed in a second. Don't waste your precious development time in reinventing wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same parsing style you're using (`rdr.LocalName = "Text"`) and then use `rdr.ReadOuterXml()`